# Extracting data from the GPU

Tags: security, architecture, x86, gpu

I suppose a "dummy" test webpage displaying one number, e.g. 1000K.
I suppose the browser is malicious, and malware changes the displayed amount into 100000K. The user confirms the transaction and sends it to a remote party.

I would like a remote server to prove that what the user is seeing is not what it has received.
One way to do this is to get the data from the GPU buffer and then extract from it the amount.

My understanding of GPUs is superficial.
Could you please give your opinion about the feasibility of the above and propose ways to achieve it?
May be GPU is not the right level of analysis?

Comment: What does a GPU have to do with any of this? The browser is what is rendering the webpage (and sending its rendered form to the GPU) in the first place.

If you want to see the true content of a webpage, use a browser you control.

Comment: yes, the user would approve the rendered 1000k, while a supposed remote server would receive 10 000K. I would like a mechanism for the remote server to know that what he is receiving and what the user is approving/have displayed to him, are not the same..hence the need to capture the true rendered content?

Comment: May be im completely missing the point. But from which part of the system can i retrieve a value displayed by the browser.

Comment: You want the *remote* machine to be able to prove what the user sees? This isn't possible; you will of course need to run *some* software on the client machine. In the context of a web page, that software *is* the browser; if it's compromised, you lose.

Comment: yes, the remote machine would need to prove what the user sees. I understand that any client side software running within the browser is not useful in this case. Hence the need to capture that data at some point other that its rendering in the browser. I assume if would be if a different format. hence, why i thought of capturing it at the GPU level (for instance), and having a client side software directly capture it from there. It might need to be a system level software? may be the GPU is not the right level? or simply not possible as suggested? need to think it through given your answer

Comment: If you get to install software other than the web browser, and you trust that other client software, why not use that other client software to do the rendering in the first place?

Comment: You don't understand. The browser would commit its fraud by *altering the content*. At that point, what the screen shows, what's on the video card, what's in memory, etc won't be able to tell you anything different.

Comment: @cHao . you are right we are right. I just need to capture this fake altered information from somewhere else other than the browser.  video card I thought was one option.

Comment: @JonathanTomer   that is a perfectly reasonable suggestion. however, we didnt want to offload the task of verification to the user. furthermore, such client side software security can be hardened by running in inside some sort of enclave. running browser in such environments is quite a hassle

Comment: im also considering the possibility that this is simply a bad idea

Comment: Once the browser alters it, as far as the hardware is concerned and will report, that is reality. Your only option is for the server to remember what it sent and compare it to the response...but at that point, the user can't change anything either.

Comment: exactly. i just want to capture that reality from some other part of the platform other than browser. if i query a compromised platform they could simply answer back with the original legitimate transaction data, while continuing to display the fake one. Therefore, i wanted to capture this data from some more trustworthy part of the system. GPU is a candidate. but may be even system memory is a possibility, is such a querying service can be implemented at system level

Comment: There is no trustworthy part of a compromised system.

Comment: that depends on your attacker model. You could assume a compromised browser, but not necessarily a compromised system software or firmware

Comment: re "client side software security can be hardened by running in inside some sort of enclave. running browser in such environments is quite a hassle": Sure, that's why I'm suggesting not using a browser at all. Write a simple client application that displays your one number in trusted fashion. Put its signature in a TPM if you like.

Comment: Can i overstep and ask how does the TPM fit in?

Comment: It makes the signature harder to tamper with. You might want that in order to ensure that someone doesn't alter your client the way they did the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea that might work--the server sends an *image* to be displayed by the browser that contains both the amount and a code. The code is known only to the server. The user has to type in the code to be sent back to the server, indicating that the user has *seen* the image containing the amount. The amount and the code in the image should be entwined in such a way that the untrusted browser cannot alter one without the other and cannot extract the code itself (like a captcha).

Comment: How would the user confirm that the code corresponds to the amount being confirmed?

Comment: Because the code and the amount are in the same image.

Comment: If I send you an image with "1000, sig(1000)" and the browser changes it to display "2000, sig(1000)" and you respond "OK sig(1000)" -- I still think you saw 1000, and you still think I sent 2000. How does either of us know I got bamboozled by malware?

Comment: The amount and the code in the image are entwined in such a way that the browser cannot alter one without the other. This approach relies on automated image processing being less sophisticated than the human visual system.

Comment: Ah, right, you did mention that. I don't think CAPTCHAs are that good, unfortunately; if it's worth writing custom malware to interfere with this particular page, it seems likely that it will be easy to build a CNN to read the number and the code, and a GAN to make a new image with a different number and the same code, that most people won't easily recognize as bogus.

Comment: I agree with everything you said except the word "easy". I think it's hard, but clearly not impossible. Security is always a balance between the cost of security measures, the cost to an attacker to subvert them, and the value of the information being protected.